# Problems with Turkish SQL Collation in SYBASE

Tags: sql, character, sybase, collation

I'm having problems with our SYBASE database set to any of the Turkish Collations, as follow

select l.OID,l.OID_KIRACI,l.IL_ADI,l.ILCE_ADI,l.MAHALLE_ADI,l.EMLAK_NO,l.KIRALANAN_YER_NO,l.KIRACI_ADI,l.KIRACI_SOYADI,l.TUZEL_KIRACI_ADI,l.KIRACI_ADRES,l.SOZLESME_NO,l.SOZLESME_TARIH,l.KIRA_BASLANGIC_TARIH,l.KIRA_BITIS_TARIH,l.ALT_KIRACI_VAR_MI,l.SOZLESME_DURUMU from V_KIRACI_SOZLESME l where l.OID_ILCE=1024 and l.OID_IL=77 and **UPPER(l.TUZEL_KIRACI_ADI) like 'yalova lisesi okul aile birliği%'** order by KIRALANAN_YER_NO,KIRACI_ADI,KIRACI_SOYADI asc

and sql dont give a result because **UPPER(l.TUZEL_KIRACI_ADI) like 'yalova lisesi okul aile birliği%'** that is changed by upper as **YALOVA LISESI OKUL AILE BIRLIĞI** so that there is no result.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select l.OID,l.OID_KIRACI,l.IL_ADI,l.ILCE_ADI,l.MAHALLE_ADI,l.EMLAK_NO,l.KIRALANAN_YER_NO,l.KIRACI_ADI,l.KIRACI_SOYADI,l.TUZEL_KIRACI_ADI,l.KIRACI_ADRES,l.SOZLESME_NO,l.SOZLESME_TARIH,l.KIRA_BASLANGIC_TARIH,l.KIRA_BITIS_TARIH,l.ALT_KIRACI_VAR_MI,l.SOZLESME_DURUMU from V_KIRACI_SOZLESME l where l.OID_ILCE=1024 and l.OID_IL=77 and ***dbo.sf_trupper(l.TUZEL_KIRACI_ADI) like dbo.sf_trupper('Yalova Lisesi Okul Aile Birliği%')*** order by KIRALANAN_YER_NO,KIRACI_ADI,KIRACI_SOYADI asc

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Sybase ASE or another type of Sybase database?
Sybase ASE is case-sensitive for data comparisons by default. This is unrelated to the character set. So, as you point out, this query will never return any rows since, essentially, 'A' != 'a'

Comment: Have you idea, 'i' return 'I' as locale that  is solved in Turkish.Corrct transform as 'i' return 'İ'